# basic authenticator in SEAM

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam

I want to do a basic authenticator handler in SEAM.
I put this in `components.xml`:

```
    <web:authentication-filter url-pattern="/test/resource/rest/*" auth-type="basic"/>
```

I have also put in `web.xml` the filter:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.BasicAuthenticationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/resource/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have created a `BasicAuthenticationServlet` class like:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationServlet extends AuthenticationFilter {

public void doFilter(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain){
//some code here
}

chain.doFilter(request, response){
//some code here
}

}
```

so I have overridden the `doFilter` method.

Now, I do not understand why it is not working?
I DID NOT find any code example for basic auth. in SEAM, all over the internet (I mean code including the filter and the class; so probably I miss something in my code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't want implement it in [Seam way](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/security.html#d0e8698)?

Answer (score 3):

I 've implemented it using

```
<web:authentication-filter url-pattern="*.seam" auth-type="basic"/>
<security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}"/>
```

and not servlets.

And in authenticate method take the user and pass like this:

```
final String username = identity.getCredentials().getUsername();
  final String password = identity.getCredentials().getPassword();
```

Comment: Sory, but that was my answer - you did it in Seam way, exaclty what I sugested.